# Jquery function on attribute change

Tags: jquery

I want to do some function when an attribute of a class changes. I wrote following JQuery:

```
var dropdown = $(".megadropdown").attr("style");

$(dropdown).change(function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

So i want to do `alert` something whne the attriubute `style` changes. It is not working. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: That's the purpose of [MutationObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), not change event

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just alert. Try:

```
$(dropdown).change(function() {
window.alert("hi");
});
```

I had this problem for some reason it worked for me.